# How would I say this sentence correctly?

Tags: sentence

> After six months of looking for jobs,
>   she got a reply from a job application
>   she posted online from Macy's asking
>   her to come to a interview.

The sentence does not sound right to me, what would be the correct way to say this?

Comment: Here's the problematic parsing for me while reading it: did she post the job application from a computer she was using in Macy's, or did the job application come from Macy's?

Comment: Yes: as it stands, it’s not incorrect, but it’s quite ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

I am not quite sure as to the need for highlighting the fact that she has been looking for job for 6 months.

How about :-

> Macy's responded to her online job application inviting her for an interview.

However, if you do need to highlight the 6 month search, then one option i can think of might be :-

> Her 6 month job search has culminated in Macy's inviting her for an interview in response to her online application

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you drop 'from a job application' as it is pretty much implied.

> After six months of looking for a job, she finally got a reply from Macy's asking her to come for an interview.

Answer (score 2):

You can start by using the correct article "an" when referring to "interview."

Answer (score 1):

You would be better to use "through" than "from" here:

> After six months of looking for jobs,
>   she got a reply *through* a job application
>   she posted online from Macy's asking
>   her to come to a interview.

Better still:

> After six months of looking for jobs,
>   she got a reply from Macy's (through an application
>   she had posted online) asking
>   her to come to a interview.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to use "as a result of" rather than "through".

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to simplify:

> An online job application finally got her an interview at Macy's after six long months of looking.

This places the fact of the application being *online* front and center. If the time period is to be emphasized:

> She looked for six long months before an online job application finally got her an interview at Macy's.

Answer (score 1):

After six months of looking for jobs, she got a reply from Macy's regarding a job application she had posted online, asking her to come to a interview.

Answer (score 1):

After six months of looking for jobs, she got a reply from Macy's to an online job application asking her to come in for an interview.